# How can I italicize part of a ggplot2 plot title when knitting the figure in an RMarkdown file?

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown

If I'm just working in R to save a plot as a PNG I'm able to use the `{ggtext}` package to incorporate basic markdown into elements of my plots, but `{ggtext}` outputs garbled text when I try using `element_markdown()` in an R chunk.

I've also tried:

```
my.title <- expression(paste0(italic("Species name"), " Rest of Title"))

ggplot... + labs(title = my.title)
```

with no luck (when knitting).

Answer (score 0):

It appears `gsub()` will do the trick, but I would be interested in knowing if there is a more elegant solution.